# Sticky/fixed dropdown menu doesn't scroll with page

Tags: html, css

So i have been trying to fix this issue for some hours now. There is a double level submenu. If the content of the sub menu goes out of viewport, when you scroll the submenu items doesn't scroll too.

[image]

[click here to view the site](http://weddingadvice.co.za)

Comment: can you add your minimised html and css code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The site is on wordpress. I added the link to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#menu-main-menu ul li{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the submenu ul that doesn't scroll, try adding a fixed height and overflow: scroll

Comment: this did work partially, but messed up the look of the menu. And besides with the static height, i am sure i wouldn't know the heights of all the devices viewing the site.